# Rails - Cannot access ckeditor_assets Table data using Ckeditor Gem & Paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ckeditor, paperclip

I'm trying to dump the data from this table to see the contents:

```
create_table "ckeditor_assets", force: true do |t|
   t.string   "data_file_name",               null: false
   t.string   "data_content_type"
   t.integer  "data_file_size"
   t.integer  "assetable_id"
   t.string   "assetable_type",    limit: 30
   t.string   "type",              limit: 30
   t.integer  "width"
   t.integer  "height"
   t.datetime "created_at"
   t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

Normally I would just do this:

```
 CkeditorAsset.all
```

but I get:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant CkeditorAsset
```

I'm pretty sure there is data in the table, as I have successfully used Ckeditor & Paperclip to upload pictures to my s3 bucket.

And if I run:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables
```

... the table name appears just fine.

What am I doing wrong here?

Why is this different from other simple "all" ActiveRecord calls I have encountered in my limited experience with RoR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gem `ckeditor` creates its models in a namespace `Ckeditor`, so to get all assets use:

```
Ckeditor::Asset.all
```

and similar:

```
Ckeditor::Picture.all
Ckditor::AttachmentFile.all
```